# Multi-Variate Linear Regression R-squared without storing input data

Tags: statistics, scipy

Anyone have a good reference for how to do a multivariate ordinary linear regression without saving the input data (and get the R-squared of the result).  The use case is a data set with too many rows to store.  The regression can be obtained by accumulating x[i]*x[j] and y * x[i], and then doing the matrix math from there, but I can't find a similar formula to get the statistics when I'm done (R-squared for starters). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a good reference, but the way I'd approach it is to
expand out the sum-of-squared expressions, and write them
in  terms of the expectations that you are accumulating.

- I use `<.>` to indicate averaging over rows of data,
  so that `<y>` is the average of the y-values,
  and so on
- at any point we can obtain the regression coefficients a[i] and b 
  from the matrix `<x[i]*x[j]>` and the vector `<y*x[i]>` as you indicated in your question
- below I'll use `sum_i{ a[i]*x[i] }` to indicate a sum over the components
  that comprise the independent variables.
- Let N be the number of data rows used

A way to compute the explained mean-squared deviation is:

```
SS_reg/N = < (f -<y> )^2 >    

         = < ( sum_i {a[i]*x[i] } + b - <y> )^2 > 
         = < sum_i { a[i]^2*x[i]^2}  +b^2 +<y>^2 +sum_i{ 2*b*a[i]*x[i]}-2*<y>* sum_i{a[i]*x[i]}-2*b*<y> >
         = sum_i { a[i]^2*<x[i]*x[i]> } +
           b^2 +
           <y>^2 + 
           2*b*sum_i{a[i]*<x[i]>} -
           2*<y>*sum_i{ a[i]*<x[i]>} -
           2*b*<y>
```

You already maintain `<x[i]*x[i]>` as the diagonal elements of the matrix for 
deriving the regression coefficients.
You will also need to maintain the averages of the independent variables
(`<x[i]>` for each `i`) as well as for the dependent variable (`<y>`)

Similar expansions can carried out for either the total or residual mean squared
errors, and then used to compute the R^2 value.